# Tables already created to insert into a cassandra keyspace to test

Tags: cassandra

I want to test my cluster a little, how data replicates, etc.

I have a cassandra cluster formed by 5 machines ( centos 7 & cassie 3.4 on them).

Are there anywhere tables already created for testing that I can import in my db in some keyspace?

If yes, please be kind enough and explain me how to import them into a keyspace and where from to take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cassandra-stress. This is great to create data for your style of table and also has some default tables.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra_win/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress.html

I highly recommend it.

Comment: This one sounds good. I will try over. One mention tho, since i am a total newbie : how to declare the columnspecs arguments?!?

Answer (score 1):

Actually , it is a lot of data in internet that can be used for testing

e.g.

- https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public
- http://bigdata-madesimple.com/70-websites-to-get-large-data-repositories-for-free/

Cassandra provide with tool cqlsh for executing CQL command as **COPY** for importing CSV data to database.

P.S.But pay attention on the fact that cqlsh  has some restriction related to timeout. That is why it would be better to use some cassandra connector to make this process more effective.